Filter a object based on another Array
I am trying to filter a object based on an another array.
data = {
  'TypeA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
  'TypeB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
  'TypeC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
}

array = ['TypeA', 'TypeB']

I want to get a new array with the values of both 'TypeA' and 'TypeB' like ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'] and remove duplicates if any also.
so far i have tried,
tTmp_Arr = data.filter(tObj => array.includes(tObj))

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Thanks,

"How large is the database you are dealing with? If it's small, you just need to loop through the data once for each datatype and then loop through the new array to check for duplicates.

each object is small only, but i may have to do this for multiple objects.. highest will the 5 arrays in an object with 20 to 35 values in array

You can't use filter on objects. You can get the result by flatmapping and then filtering as:


const data = {
  'TypeA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
  'TypeB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
  'TypeC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
};

const array = ['TypeA', 'TypeB'];

const result = array
  .flatMap(key => data[key] || []) 
  .filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item) === index);
  
console.log(result);




Please don’t deduplicate like that, it’s O(n^2). Consider [...new Set(array.flatMap(key => data[key]))] as a concrete alternative, but I would wrap that in a unique function or use an existing one.

@Ry- Thats a good solution with better performance. Please add this it as an answer.

To achieve this, start by using the flatMap() method to map each element of the array (which contains keys) to its corresponding values in the data object. Secondly, wrap the result in a Set to remove any duplicate values. Finally, convert the result back into an array using Array.from().


const data = {
  'TypeA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
  'TypeB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
  'TypeC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
};

const array = ['TypeA', 'TypeB'];

const result = Array.from(
  new Set(
    array.flatMap(type => data[type] || [])
  )
);

console.log(result);




This answer looks like the best practice to me.

Here example using only for..loops


const data = {
    'TypeA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
    'TypeB': ['B1', 'A1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'A2'],
    'TypeC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
}

const checkDublicate = (array, val) => {
    let dublicate = false
    array.forEach((element) => {
        if (element === val) dublicate = true
    })
    return dublicate
}

const filterFunction = (dataTypes, data) => {
    const temp = []
    for (let i = 0; i < dataTypes.length; i++) {
        const dataBase = data[dataTypes[i]]
        dataBase.forEach(element => {
            const check = checkDublicate(temp, element)
            if (!check) temp.push(element)
        });
    }
    return temp
}

const dataTypes = ['TypeA', 'TypeB']
const array = filterFunction(dataTypes, data)
console.log(array)




Here's another working example using array.reduce() with a for..of loop:


const data =
{
  'TypeA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
  'TypeB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
  'TypeC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
  
  // EXTRA
  'TypeExtra':
  [
    'A1', 'B1', 'C1',
    'EXTRA VALUE',
  ]
};

const array = ['TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeExtra'];

const result = array.reduce
(
  ( result, index ) =>
  {
    for ( const item of data[index] )
    {
      if ( ! result.includes(item) )
      {
        result.push(item);
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  },
  []
);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }



